# Issue with numbers that contain a "." like 1.11 or .111

Tags: javascript

The user needs to enter a number between 0 and 9999 in a text box and I want to check if this string is valid integer number between 0 and 9999. If the user enters more than one number in the text box like for example 16 and 1 then the verification should return false.

I have an issue if there is a "." in the string. 1.11 returns true but it should return false and .111 changes into 0.111 and returns true instead of false. I want that a string with a "." returns false. How can I do that?

I have tested the following cases:

```
0 returns true
1117 returns true
9999 returns true
17000 returns false
0,1 returns false
A1 returns false
16 1 returns false
16_1 returns false
1.11 returns true but it should return false
.111 returns true but it should return false
```

**1.11 and .111 are not working correctly because they return true instead of false.**

What is wrong with the code?

```
handlers.CheckTextboxstring = function (args, context)
{
  var TextboxNumber = validate(args.Textboxstring);
  return TextboxNumber.NewNumber;
}

function validate(str)
{
    if(!isEmptyOrSpaces(str))
    {
      let num=Number(str);
      if(num!==NaN)
      {
         if(num >= 0 && num <= 9999)
         {
           return{NewNumber: "true, number is in range."};
         }
         else
         {
            return{NewNumber: "false, number not in range."};
         }
      }
      else
      {
          return{NewNumber: "false, string is NaN."};
      }
    }
    else
    {
        return{NewNumber: "false, the string is not a number."};
    }
}

function isEmptyOrSpaces(str)
{
    return str === null || str.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
}
```

Comment: what about `0000`?

Comment: What about something like checking `Number.isInteger(num)`

Comment: why not using regex for number only like ^[0-9]*$ then use condition (num >= 0 && num <= 9999)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a regular expression and look for one to four digits.

```js
function check(s) {
    return /^([1-9]\d{0,3}|0)$/.test(s);
}

['0', '1117', '9999', '17000', '0,1', 'A1', '16 1', '16_1', '1.11', '.111', '1.0', '00'].map(s => console.log(check(s)));
```

Comment: if they don't want leading zeros, then `/^0$|^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$/`

Comment: @georg Thanx. I don't want leading zeros. Is it still necessary to do the NaN check if I use function check(s)? For example: Number.isNan(s) at the beginning of the function?

Comment: no, you can use just the regular expression. please see edit for only zero or a number without leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) represents a floating-point number, meaning that it can handle integers as well as decimals. In that sense, there's nothing "wrong" with your code, you just need to add additional checks to make sure that the `Number` you've read in is actually an integer.

For that, you can use [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) to check the value once you've casted it, or you can skip the read-and-check by using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) instead of `Number()`.

Or, if you want to take a different approach entirely, as @NinaScholz pointed out, you can use a regular expression directly to ensure that there's nothing in the string except for 1 to 4 numeric digits.

Side note: You have `if(num!==NaN)` in your code, but for reasons that I won't go into here, `NaN !== NaN` will still return `true`. Use [`Number.isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) instead.